# I need help finding the name of that function

Tags: html, css

I am making a system, and would like to know what is the name of that function that people use to teach to use a system.
The screen is usually dark and only one part is clear.

My boss says he's a wizard, but I do not want a stepper.

I'll leave an image I did as an example:

[image]

Comment: Onboarding.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find this feature under multiple names :

1. Walkthrough
2. Guide tour
3. Step by step guide

You can find top guide tour here : https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/328/top-10-best-tour-website-guide-javascript-and-jquery-plugins

Comment: Perfect! That was exactly it. Thank you!